# Use "@" in html5 input pattern attribute with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, email

Does anyone know how I can use a "@" within the pattern attribute on a HTML5 email input having a MVC page?

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$">
```

At runtime I get this error:

> "[" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

When I use "data-pattern" instead of "pattern" I can escape it with "@@", but with "pattern" that fails too.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It can be done 2 ways:

Render the "@" through razor:

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@("@")[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$">
```

With a HTML encode:

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+&#64;[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$">
```

Comment: Great stuff, not sure why this hasn't got more upvotes!

Comment: I know this is old, but any reason why `@@` does not work in this case?